# How to execute the link href automatically

Tags: html, class, href

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ui-content content-padding">

    <h3>Buttons</h3>
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <a href="#2btnPopup" class="ui-btn" data-rel="popup">2btn popup</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="2btnPopup" class="ui-popup">
    <div class="ui-popup-header">Power saving mode</div>
    <div class="ui-popup-content">
        Turning on Power
        saving mode will
        limit the maximum
        power
    </div>
    <div class="ui-popup-footer ui-grid-col-2">
        <button id="2btnPopup-cancel" class="ui-btn">Cancel</button>
        <button id="2btnPopup-ok" class="ui-btn">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="popupToast" class="ui-popup ui-popup-toast">
    <div class="ui-popup-content">
        Saving contacts to sim on Samsung 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open the html page I want to execute the 2btn popup button action automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is already some code or some action associated to that button?

Comment: when I click on the <a href......> a window appear with the two buttons (ok + cancel)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

**Html**

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/" id="linktoJsFiddle" >2btn popup</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var linktoJsFiddle = $('#linktoJsFiddle').attr('href');
window.location = linktoJsFiddle;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net//komanchero/Pdmj6/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are already using jQuery (The markup you have seems to be from the jQuery UI package), so just grab the button by it's ID and emulate a click on it.

In case you have more than one button in your document, give it a unique ID, I used "popupButton1" in this case as an example:

```
<a href="#2btnPopup" class="ui-btn" id="popupButton1" data-rel="popup">2btn popup</a>
```

Then, once the document loads and the DOM is ready, just emulate a click on the button:

```
$(function(){
   $('#popupButton1').click();
});
```

Comment: I edit my code like this, still no working: pastebin.com/J0eQwenk . I got null null null